# HTML Email just showing html in the message

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send mail using the simple mail() function in php and complete the formatting in HTML

PHP Code:

```
$headers = "From: ClubbedIn\r\n";
$to = $userEmail;
$subject = $rowclub['clubName']." - New Event: ".$eventName;
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<img src="http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebsiteChangeRequestForm/images/wcrf-header.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';    
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Event Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($eventName) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Date:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($newdate) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Time:</strong> </td><td>" . $startTime2." - ".$endTime2 . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Description:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($desc) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

    //$message = "Event Name: ".$eventName."\nDate: ".$newdate."\nTime: ".$startTime2." - ".$endTime2."\nDescription: ".$desc;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

However the email just ends up looking like this:
[image]

The html does not work for some reason?

Comment: have you set the correct headers? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - example 4

Comment: That's not how you send a HTML E-Mail, you'll need some specific headers at least

Comment: I would advise you to use PHPMailer or another powerful library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the proper headers:

```
$headers = "From: ClubbedIn\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to make changes to the header to indicate its HTML email. Try this:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers.= "From: ".$from_address."\r\n";
```

Update: changed \n to \r\n as suggested by Matt Bryant to meet rfc 2822 specification.

Comment: Unless the php `mail()` function does something special, this does not meet RFC 2822.  Lines must end with `\r\n`.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the update. I'll update my answer. This same code works for some of my applications though but that could be a specific server setting I guess.

Comment: It is very possible that your mailserver converts it without warning, but the spec states they must be terminated by `CRLF`.

Answer (score 2):

To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
// Additional headers
$headers .= "To: Mary <mary@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com\r\n";
```

(php.net)